# JS не отображаеться в браузере , хотя все правильно подключил , но в консоле браузера ничего не виводиться . В чем может быть проблема?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, visual-studio-code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ActiveBox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta name="vieport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
</head>
```

Подключил библиотеку jquery

```
   <skript src="app.js"></skript> в body подключил JS 





 $(function(){
    console.log("rabotaet");

});
```

Прописую в файле джава скрипт для проверки . В консоле браузера ничего не видно . как так ?
буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: `skript` - это шутка такая?)

Comment: .......skript  ???

Answer (score 1):

Lucky John!
Нужно немного исправить название тега.

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое .